Does flipping a chiral helimagnet reverse both the its Dzyaloshinskii-Moriya Interaction (DMI) and chirality?
I'm working with chiral helimagnets, and I'm trying to understand the effects of flipping the sample on its magnetic properties. Specifically, I'm curious if flipping the sample upside down changes both the Dzyaloshinskii-Moriya Interaction (DMI) sign and the observed chirality of the magnetic spiral.
Here’s an analogy I’m considering: if I coil my left hand clockwise with the thumb pointing up, flipping it turns the coil direction to anti-clockwise with my thumb pointing down. Does this analogy apply to the DMI and chirality in chiral helimagnets?
Are there specific cases (such as interface-sensitive DMI) where this effect is more pronounced?
Would this depend on whether the DMI is driven by bulk vs. interface effects?
I'd appreciate any insights or references on this topic!
